# sql How can I put a select into an avg

Tags: sql

i need something like:

Select avg(select distinct ...)
from...

but it doesn't work

FROM COMMENT:

```
select avg( select distinct x.money
            from departmentx x inner join
                 departmenty y
                 on x.identity = y.identity
            union
            select distinct y.money
            from departmentx x inner join
                 departmenty y
                 on x.identity = y.identity
            where money not null
          )
from department
```

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't work'? Please elaborate and provide your **full code**. Also, definitely `SQL` right, ***not*** `MySQL`?

Comment: Flagged as `Too Broad`.

Comment: sql..and its

select 
avg(
 select distinct  x.money
from departmentx x
inner join departmenty y
on x.identity = y.identity
union
select distinct y.money
from departmentx x
inner join departmenty y
on x.identity = y.identity
where  money not null
)
from department

Comment: Your query really doesn't make sense.  For instance, you are not using any columns from `department`.  And, the use of `avg(distinct)` usually indicates an error in the code.  When asking a question, include sample data and desired results.  I would suggest that you ask another question that better describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: oracle
i tried but i cant ask another for a couple of days

i have 1 table with a foreign key directing to itself, and it has a money column, and i  need to get the average money of those who has a specific id, or where a specific data (here i wrote money is not null, to make it more simple) is given

Comment: Why DISTINCT's in the sub-query? UNION will removed all duplicates...

Answer (score 1):

The following *may* be the intention of the code that you have written:

```
select avg(money)
from (select distinct x.money
      from departmentx x inner join
           departmenty y
           on x.identity = y.identity
      union
      select distinct y.money
      from departmentx x inner join
           departmenty y
           on x.identity = y.identity
      where money is not null
     ) m
```

I've left the "weirdisms":

- You do not need `distinct` in the subqueries.  `union` takes care of that.
- You do not need `money is not null`.  `avg()` ignores `NULL`.
- You probably shouldn't name a column `money` because that is the name of a built-in type.